# Which file contains asterisk in unix

Tags: unix

All

Here i post my doubt about files with asterisk, First i create one file

```
touch test*
```

If i check `ls -lrt` it shows the `test*` file in the current. 
Then i removed that file using `rm *`.
Then i create two files which are `test1*` `test2*` using same touch command. 
If i check `ls -lrt`. 
It displays the two files that are `test1*` and `test2*`.
Again i create `test*` using touch command , now i check `ls -lrt`. 
This time it will not display the file `test*`.
Why the `test*` file is not listed ?

Thanks & regards

Answer (score 5):

As * is used by your shell as universal character, when you write

```
touch test*
```

your shell will tranform it into

```
touch test1* test2*
```

If you want to create 'test*', use simple quote, which inhibit the globing function.

```
touch 'test*'
```

Answer (score 1):

Normally touch command is used to create a empty file.
if file is already there it will change only the access time.

first time you are using the touch test*
that there is no test file so it will creates file names as test*

second time you are using touch test* that, time the current directory having test1*  and test2* files,
so it will expand into test1* and test2* .

In that case it will change only the access time of the both file.

if you want to create one more time test* file means you can use double quotes.